# MDX " BETWEEN .. AND" CONDITION

Tags: mdx, pentaho

I am using one MDX Equation as shown below.

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY { [Operator].[Total],[Operator].[Total] .Children } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { [Circle].[Total], [Circle].[Total] .Children } ON ROWS FROM 
[16CircleWiseRoamingFailure5] 
WHERE 
( [Measures].[Count], [RoamingFlag].[INRoaming], [Date].[${yesterday}] , [SuccessFailureDetails].[FAILURE] )
```

here i am passing one function called "yesterday" which gives only yesterdays data.

Now i want to find values within an interval e.g. between month or between days. Can anyone tell me the syntax...?

Answer (score 0):

In Analysis Services, you can use a range, using the ":" operator.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146001.aspx

Don't know if it works in Pentaho